# Compact Space: Locally Continuous $\implies$ Uniformly Continuous

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity, compactness, uniform-continuity

Given metric spaces.
Prove that any locally continuous function on a compact space is uniformly continuous!

Comment: what does "locally continuous" mean?

Comment: just the ordinary continuity ;) see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity#Local_continuity_versus_global_uniform_continuity

Comment: then don't call it by a name nobody uses ;)

Comment: Yes I know it just looked better in the title ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By local continuity there is a delta for any point:
$$d(x,z)<\delta(z)\implies d(f(x),f(z))<\frac{1}{2}\epsilon$$
By compactness there is finite cover:
$$X=\bigcup_{i=1}^N B_{\frac{1}{2}\delta(z_{i_0})}(z_i)$$
Thus any two points close enough:
$$d(x,y)<\min_{i=1\ldots N}\frac{1}{2}\delta(z_i)$$
belong to one common ball:
$$d(x,z_{i_0})<\frac{1}{2}\delta(z_{i_0})<\delta(z_{i_0})$$
$$d(y,z_{i_0})<d(x,z_{i_0})+d(x,y)<\frac{1}{2}\delta(z_{i_0})+\frac{1}{2}\delta(z_{i_0})=\delta(z_{i_0})$$
and therefore satisfy:
$$d(f(x),f(y))<d(f(z),f(z_{i_0}))+d(f(x),f(z_{i_0}))<\frac{1}{2}\epsilon+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon=\epsilon$$

Comment: @Downvoter: Could u plz explain!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I conjecture that the downvoter believed Conifold's answer (or something similar) and therefore thought that yours was unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Complicated but necessary, isn't it?

Comment: I didn't check that every $\frac12$ in your answer is necessary, but some of them are surely necessary, as I indicated in a comment on Conifold's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by "locally continuous" you simply mean "continuous" this is a classical result. You can find the proof in many texts. You can approach it by assuming the function is not uniformly continuous and use that assumption to construct a suitable sequence, and use compactness to deduce a contradiction. Or, you can take a more topological approach and first prove the Lebesgue number lemma. Uniform continuity of continuous functions is an easy consequence.

Answer (score 1):

For every point $x$ find a ball over which the function doesn't change more than by $\epsilon$. The balls of half the radius still cover the set, and since the set is compact there is a finite subcover. The smallest radius $\delta$ of these finitely many smaller balls works for the whole set. Indeed, any two points within $\delta$ of each other will be in one of the larger original balls by the triangle inequality, and values at them can  differ by no more than $\epsilon$.

Comment: I think you need some $\delta/2$ work in this proof *as in Freeze_S's answer.  As it stands, you seem to assume that any two points that are within $\delta$ of each other are together in one of the sets in your finite subcover.

Comment: Good catch, I fixed it without halving explicitly.